# How can Java apps use tray icons in Ubuntu >= 13.04 (with AppInicator)

Tags: java, ubuntu, swt, system-tray, trayicon

The system tray was deprecated in Ubuntu 11.04 in favour of the new AppIndicator. Since then,  SWT applications couldn't show an icon unless the user used a whitelisting workaround included for backwards compatibility. Version 13.04 now removes that workaround, meaning SWT applications (which don't support appindicator) can no longer generate tray icons.

How do you guys go about making tray icon applications using Java? Preferably in a way that works both on Windows and Linux, and not necessarily with SWT any more. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, who knew. This exists in *awt*, so it's natively supported: [SystemTray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SystemTray.html), and it works with AppIndicator in Ubuntu 13.04.

That said, there's a [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6453521) that makes the icon transparent background amateur-gray :(

Comment: Give a small code example, and then feel free to accept your own answer.